# Why have useState hooks if state can be assigned directly?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In React, why should I use `useState` if I can just set a variable using `let` and mutate that instead?
For example:

```
const ProfileProvider = ({roles, children}) => {
  let adminRole = false;
  if(roles.includes('admin')) {
    adminRole = true;
  }

  return <ProfileContext.Provider
  value={{
    adminRole
  }}>
    {children}
  </ProfileContext.Provider>;
 }
```

Whats the difference between setting adminRole in this way vs `useState`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With useState you will directly tell to react that your view needs to be updated to reflect the changes that you did with your value. Using let, even changing it for some reason it will not update.

Comment: But this code still works, if the if statement is true then it will still set the value

Comment: It works, but if you trigger an update for it react will not cover it. Your code is right, you don't need to use useState

Answer (score 0):

We should not mutate state variables directly . React works on virtual dom. React will not identify when to update and render with updated data. For that we need to update state. We can also use redux and reducer which stores state data globally. You can refer this link. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: But this code still works, when I set adminRole to true in the if statement, it runs the provider with the value true

Comment: My answer is for question "Why have useState". Code given in question will work for pure functions. But that pure function could be child of functions have state lifcycle.